# Pattern based highlighting tool in edge

Tags: software-development, microsoft-edge

I am looking for a **pattern-based** highlighter tool which can help developers in highlighting certain patterns in certain colours.

Example: *return* in yellow, *case* in blue, and so on!

Similar tools are available for other browsers:

1. Firefox: [Highlight This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/highlightthis/)
2. Chrome: [Multi-Highlight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji)

Comment: @ThomasWeller, the examples I gave are tools which can help me highlight certain words on no matter which page I browse to. It does the job by allowing the pattern-based search. I want similar thing for EDGE browser.

Comment: Ok, I see. I had a look at the other browser extensions. I went through the [list of Edge extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/collections/edgeextensions/pc?s=store&skipitems=0) but it seems there is none

Comment: true, hence I asked once if someone might be using something.